# Implementation ideas for authentication between two parties

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cryptography

I would like to implement an authentication between two parties (for example a user and a bank) but I stumbled upon a "design/implementation" doubt.
I need to do this steps:

1. user to communicate his address [something related to my project]
   encrypted with bank's public key
2. bank decrypt address and send to that address some data (for authentication purpouses) encrypted
   with user public key
3. user decrypt and use digital signature to sign that data and send it
   back (like before and blablabla)

I've created the server [with nodejs->express] which provides endpoints for:

- registration of users/banks [or other requesters of authentication]
- encryption with pub key
- decryption with private key sent as a parameter
- digital signature

The question is:

Now, are banks that needs to call with the right sequence my endpoints to authenticate users or should I create a new Endpoint like /authenticate and in some way automatically retrieve the user+bank requests to my endpoints?
The first option seems more like an api service but I don't know if it's the only way to do it.
And for the second one i have no idea how to do it.

(Sorry for my bad english I'm Italian, I do only know pizza pasta peperoni language)

Comment: How is a private key private if it's sent as a parameter? Or the decryption result is sent? How will that not be vulnerable to man in the middle?

Comment: If the Channel is secure (like using ssl/tls) is it MitM secured? Btw thanks for replying! I need to have a discussion to improve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would an answer which takes the intermediary out of the transaction, be useful to you?

That is, one which is decentralised and goes point to point directly between customer and merchant. Before it gets recorded on a ledger.

Comment: Hello Robin! Thanks for trying to helping me!
Your solution seems kinda right.
You suggest to delete my node js server with its endpoints and create what? like a smart contract? i really don't know how to start, can you point me some more links/information?
Thanks a lot and i hope you had a great day!

Comment: sorry for writing such a long answer :0
By the way the node js server is, in reality, directly connected to the blockchain, because i've written the entire blockchain inside that app.

Comment: Edit: that blockchain is inside a nodejs app, which creates an executable node. Inside that app, there is a method which starts the server on port xyz that provides the mentioned above endpoints. Isn't It kinda similar to a smart contract?

Comment: Simone. Have you read the Bitcoin white paper? It may answer your questions.